# How to efficiently combine two large Pandas dataframes by datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to large datasets and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I have two large data frames that i need to merge based on datetime.

Dataframe 1:

1. 250 million rows of data
2. Datetime index
3. Colums containing motion sensor values

Dataframe 2:

1. 50 million row of data
2. Datetime index
3. Columns containing easting and northings

I want to add easting and northings from dataframe2 to dataframe 1 based on the closest datetime. I have tried a few different methods (i.e. `df.index.get_loc`, `df.interpolate`) but the processing time is huge and memory becomes unstable very quickly. Is there a way to process this without iterating through the dataframes? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.merge_asof` will help match based on the closest time.

Comment: Thanks mate. Reduced processing time from hours to minutes.